# Removing a table row and displayed entity using jQuery

Tags: jquery, servlets, jstl

I have a table generated like so:

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Članovi postave:</th>
    <c:if test="${not empty user}">
        <c:if test="${user.admin eq true}">
        <td><a href="AddClanPostave">Dodaj novog člana postave</a></td>
    </c:if>
        </c:if>
</tr>
<c:forEach items="${noviFilm.clanoviPostave}" var="clanPostave">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${clanPostave}"/><br><td>
    <c:if test="${not empty user}">
        <c:if test="${user.admin eq true}">
        <form action="RemoveServlet" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="type" value="movie"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="entity" value="${clanPostave.id}"/>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Remove"></td>
        </form>
        </c:if>
    </c:if>
    </tr> 
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

Now, I'm pretty new to web programming. I understand servlets, .jsp and el and jstl for the most part, and I'm starting to learn jQuery. This code here calls the servlet in question, removes the given entity from the appropriate list and reloads the page, but I was wondering if there might be a quicker and easier way to do this using jQuery?

Something like:

```
$(".delete").live('click', function(event) {
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
});
```

The problem is that I'm not sure whether or not this works correctly on the list, and not only the display.

A side question - is there a more efficient way to get a hold of the selected object. What I'm doing now is storing his UUID id attribute, then going through the list and comparing the toString values. Is there a better method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the real question? Is it broken?

You shouldnt use `live`, rather use an up-to-date jQuery version and write it like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete", function(event) {
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
});
```

And while you're at it, improve the HTML :-)

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Clanovi postave:</th>
    <c:if test="${not empty user}">
        <c:if test="${user.admin eq true}">
        <td><a href="AddClanPostave">Dodaj novog clana postave</a></td>
    </c:if>
        </c:if>
    </tr>
  <thead>
  <tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${noviFilm.clanoviPostave}" var="clanPostave">
      <tr>
          <td><c:out value="${clanPostave}"/><br><td>
      <c:if test="${not empty user}">
          <c:if test="${user.admin eq true}">
          <form action="RemoveServlet" method="post">
              <input type="hidden" name="type" value="movie"/>
              <input type="hidden" name="entity" value="${clanPostave.id}"/>
          <td><input type="submit" value="Remove"></td>
          </form>
          </c:if>
      </c:if>
      </tr> 
    </c:forEach>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The thing is, I'm not sure if it's broken, as I can't test it until I get the model, which should be tomorrow. This is all in theory, and I'm asking beforehand only because I'll have about six hours to fully plug in the model and make sure everything is working properly. My main concern was if jQuery will call the `noviFilm.clanoviPostave.remove(clanPostave)` method. I'll mark this as the correct answer when I set up the model if everything works.

Could you answer my side question, at the end of the post?